# space between paragraph and list

Tags: spacing, lists, paragraphs

In this code, I'm confused about why the space between `First paragraph` and `Second paragraph` is not equal to the space between `Second paragraph` and `First bullet`. How can I make them equal?

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.7ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\topmargin -0.5in
\textheight 9in
\oddsidemargin 0in
\evensidemargin 0 in
\textwidth 6.4in
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\linespread{0.9}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{enumerate}
\begin{document}
\large

{\Large\bfseries First paragraph\par}

{\large\bfseries Second paragraph\par}
\begin{itemize}

\item First bullet
\item Second bullet

\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can customize lists and their spacing using the excellent [`enumitem`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/enumitem) package.

In your example, you might like to use

```
\begin{itemize}[topsep=\parskip]
```

for local customization, or else

```
\setlist[itemize]{topsep=\parskip}
```

for global customization in the preamble.

I'd also recommend using the [`geometry`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/geometry) package to customize page dimensions, and you should almost always load the [`hyperref`](http://texdoc.net/pkg/hyperref) package last (unless it is a member of [Which packages should be loaded after hyperref instead of before?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1863/which-packages-should-be-loaded-after-hyperref-instead-of-before))

```
\documentclass[11pt]{article}
\usepackage[top=1in,textheight=9in,textwidth=6.4in]{geometry}
\linespread{0.9}
\setlength{\parskip}{0.7ex}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}

\large

{\Large\bfseries First paragraph\par}

{\large\bfseries Second paragraph}
\begin{itemize}[topsep=\parskip]
\item First bullet
\item Second bullet
\end{itemize}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I tried compiling your code, but still the space between First paragraph and Second paragraph is less than the space between Second paragraph and First bullet. Any idea why that might be?

Comment: @PaulS. you're welcome :) Sorry about that, I had a stray blank line- try it now

Comment: My eyes might be fooling me, but I believe the first space is still a little less than the second space

Comment: Anyway, I think it's good enough!